# How to enter data into firebase when database rule are false?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to send the data when database rules are false can anyone please give me the code for that into firebase using android.

Comment: Do you have some code now that is not working?

Answer (score 0):

If your security rules don't allow any regular user access to the database:

```
// These rules don't allow anyone read or write access to your database
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

Then the only code that can write to the database, is code that doesn't run as a regular user, i.e. code that uses one of the [Firebase Admin SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start).

You can also enter data in the Firebase console, which also accesses the database as an administrative user.